How to prove $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ using elementary techniques?
Prove $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.
My try by contradiction:
Assume there exist $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q} $ such that:
$\sqrt{2}=a + b \sqrt[3]{2} +c \sqrt[3]{4}$.
Squaring both sides, we have:
$2=(a^{2}+4bc)+(2ab+2c^{2}) \sqrt[3]{2}+(b^{2}+2ac)\sqrt[3]{4}$, which leads to:
$(a^{2}+4bc)=2$
$(2ab+2c^{2})=0$
$(b^{2}+2ac)=0$
But how could I reach contradiction?

have you learned about degrees of field extensions yet?

@hunter Yes I learned it.

Are you trying to do a "elementary" proof that does not use field theory, only number theory?
Because otherwise, there is a very easy proof.

@kabelabel Yes I am trying to see whether it is possible to be proved using elementary techniques.

I see. You should edit the post and write that in explicitly then :)

@kabelabel Ok, I will edit it now.

Have you tried just solving the system?

@JulioPuerta The system is complicated so I wondered if there would be simple way to continue with complications.

It is actually not that difficult to solve...

Still, it is worth looking at an algebraic proof, e.g., here.

By the first equation, if $bc=0$, then $a^2=2$ suggests $\sqrt 2$ is rational hence impossible. Therefore  we may assume $bc\not=0$, and $a=-\frac{c^2}{b}$ from the second equation. Now apply this to the third equation, we have
$$b^2-2\cdot \frac{c^2}{b} \cdot c = 0 \Rightarrow  (\frac{b}{c})^3=2$$
which is again impossible as $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not rational.

So, if we are only allowed to use number theory, my first instinct is to use infinite descent. Note that if $a,b,c$ have some common denominator $d$, your $3$ equations turn out to have rational solutions if and only if the equations
$$a^2 + 4bc - 2d^2 = 0$$
$$ab + 2c^2 = 0$$
$$b^2 + 2ac = 0$$
Have integer solutions with $d \neq 0$. We'll refer to these as (1),(2), and (3). Thus, we can use basic divisibility arguments: $a$ is divisible by $2$ via (1), so $d$ must also be divisible by $2$ (we can arrive at this by dividing (1) down by $2$). We have that $b$ must be divisible by $2$ via (3), and since $ab$ is thus divisible by $4$, $c$ must be divisible by $2$ via (2).
This is all to say $a,b,c$ and $d$ are all divisible by two, so by homogenity of these equations you can just divide any solution by two to get a smaller one, which is a contradiction.

Using your equations, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
a^2 + 4bc & = 2\\
ab+c^2 & = 0 \\
b^2+2ac & = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
It is easy to see that $a\neq 0$ since otherwise $bc=\tfrac{1}{2}$, but $b=c=0$. Similarly $b\neq 0$ since then $a^2=2$, not possible over $\mathbb Q$.
So we can use the third equation to get $c=-\tfrac{b^2}{2a}$. With this the system becomes
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
a^2 -2\tfrac{b^3}{a} & = 2\\
ab+\tfrac{b^4}{4a^2} & = 0 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
a^3 -2a-2b^3 & = 0\\
4a^3+b^3 & = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
From the last equation we get $b^3=-4a^3$ and plugging back into the first equation, we get $9a^3-2a=0$, or $a(9a^2-2)=0$. As we said before, $a\neq 0$, so this means $a^2=\tfrac{2}{9}$, which obviously does not have rational solutions.
